# Can this probability question be done with simple python coding in loop (if, else ,elif)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Q. Suppose that you roll four 6-sided dice. Estimate the probability that the die rolls are such
that the four dice can be paired off so that one pair sums to 7 and the other sums to 9.
Below is the coding I tried in Cocalc and it worked. 
I was looking for some answer that will use the loop (if,else,elif).

```
import random
def probability (sum_1,sum_2):
    a = 0
    for i in range(0,100000):
        dice_1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice_3 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice_4 = random.randint(1,6)
        if dice_1+dice_2+dice_3+dice_4==16:
            if dice_1+dice_2==9 or dice_1+dice_3==9 or dice_1+dice_4==9 or dice_2+dice_3==9 or dice_2+dice_4==9 or dice_3+dice_4==9:
                a+= 1
    probability = a/100000
    return probability 

probability (7,9)
0.07509
```

Comment: I think you should make it clearer in your problem statement what you need help with. On the face of it, it looks like you have a workable approach. (I didn't try it, but it looks like it could work.)

Comment: Why does neither `sum_1` nor `sum_2` being used in the function?

Comment: What’s the issue here, exactly? Your code, which you say is working, already uses a loop etc.

Comment: I was looking for another way to compute it using loop